# Inclination problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry

Find the equation of a line through the point $(-2,5)$ with in angle of inclination of $45^\circ$.

I attempted the problem by assuming that the inclination is with the x-axis.  Since $y=x$ resembles a line that goes through the x-axis, and has an angle of $45^\circ$.  I calculated that the slope has to be $1$.

Therefore the equation is:

> $y=x+7$

Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**: Slope $m = \tan (45^{\circ}) = 1 \implies y - 5 = 1(x - (-2)) \implies y = ...$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is correct. A way to check this is to insert the given point and see whether or not it satisfies your equation:

$$5=-2+7$$

It does!